# Calculate 3rd vertex of equilateral triangle given 2 vertices

Tags: geometry

The given vertices are $(-4,3)$ and $(0,0)$.

I've attempted this question a few times but I keep getting the same result which looks like a terrible result. Unfortunately I don't have the solutions either so I don't know if my answer is right.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the substitution or factorisation or that the answer is just meant to be weird. Can anyone help?

Sorry about the first image, it's pretty messy.

**first page of working:**

[image]

**second page of working:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: You can do this much more easily using a rotation matrix - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 1):

No, it looks like you did everything right. Running it through the distance formula, the point $(\frac{-4+3\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{3}{2}+2\sqrt{3})$ is 5 units away from $(0,0)$ and $(-4,3)$. I think the "weirdness" you see is a consequence of the fact that equilateral triangles have an interior angle of $60^{\circ}$, which is going to naturally lead to a lot of $\sqrt{3}$'s cropping up since $\sin(60^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.